# apt install を実行してもパッケージが正常にダウンロードできない

Tags: ubuntu, apt

mini.iso からインストールした Ubuntu18.04 に、スクレイピングのために firefox をインストールしようとしたのですが、失敗しました。
どうすればよいでしょうか。

```
$ sudo apt install firefox -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  fonts-lyx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  firefox
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 589 not upgraded.
Need to get 54.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 212 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Ign:1 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 firefox amd64 79.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 firefox amd64 79.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
  Connection failed [IP: 160.26.2.187 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_79.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 160.26.2.187 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

**その他、環境や確認したこと:**

- プロキシは使用していません。
- メッセージ内のURLやIPアドレスに ping が通ることは確認しています。
- パッケージソースを富山大からJAISTに変更しても同じような結果になりました。
- 事前に `apt clean` と `apt update` も実行しましたが、インストールに失敗します。

### 追記

自己回答した通り、ファイルからのインストールは成功したのですが、今度は apt upgrade が出来なくなりました。元々は問題なく更新無しで正常終了していました。

#### 手順

1. sudo apt autoremove
2. sudo apt update
3. sudo apt upgrade

#### 結果

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
...
E: Failed to fetch http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/console-setup/console-setup-linux_1.194ubuntu3_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 160.26.2.187 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tzdata/tzdata_2020a-0ubuntu0.20.04_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 160.26.2.187 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-5.4.0-42_5.4.0-42.46_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 160.26.2.187 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/llvm-toolchain-10/llvm-10-dev_10.0.0-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 160.26.2.187 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: curl や wget コマンドでパッケージのURLをダウンロードしようとした場合はどうなるでしょうか？ / プロキシを使用しておらず、ping も通るなら一時的な問題のような気もしますが…

Comment: パッケージのURLというのは Failed to fetch の *.deb ですよね wgetで成功しました

Comment: 関係があるかはわかりませんが、問題のファイルのスタンプが2020-07-29 13:30でした、apt、wgetを実行したのはこの時刻の前後ではありませんか？

Comment: apt installに失敗したのは30日と31日ですね　手元に環境がないので明日もう一度やってみます

Answer (score 1):

2020-08-03 に再度 `apt install` を実行しましたが、同様に失敗しました。

代わりに、予め wget で入手したファイルを以下の手順でインストールすることに成功し、ヘッドレスモードで起動したり、Python の Selenium から操作することが出来ました。
よって一応の目的は達成しました。

```
$ sudo apt install ./firefox_79.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
```